# Rewrite URL in a cleaner way for blog articles

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

This is the original URL:

```
www.example.com/article/index.php?p=general&t=how-cinema-changed-our-life&i=1
```

I would to rewrite it like this:

```
www.example.com/article/general/1/how-cinema-changed-our-life
```

Is it possible? And of course, is it SEO friendly in this way?

I think that a better solution can be:

```
www.example.com/general/article/how-cinema-changed-our-life
```

But I don't know if I can retrieve the "i" PHP variable and how to edit it.

Comment: Rewrites go the other way.  You want to rewrite `www.example.com/article/general/1/how-cinema-changed-our-life` to `www.example.com/article/index.php?p=general&t=how-cinema-changed-our-life&i=1`.   In other words, when a request comes in for the friendly URL, you want it internally rewritten to be handled by `index.php`

Comment: If you had been using the URLs with  parameters you'll want to **redirect** them (not rewrite them) to the friendly URL

Comment: It isn't clear how the `i` parameter is supposed to be handled.  Does it always have a value of "1" or can it have other values as well?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller `i` is a variable so it will change

Comment: Is it the Id of the post or is something that has "1" as the default value?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It is the id of the article from the server

Comment: There is no way that rewrite rules can look up the article id based on the slug, so if index.php needs the id to produce the page, there is no way can use rewrite rules to remove it from the URL.  Although you could conceivably change index.php so that it can retrieve content from the database by slug rather than by id.

Comment: I can use parse_url or something else, but I don't know how to rewrite the url with htaccess, so anyone can explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this URL:

`www.example.com/article/general/1/how-cinema-changed-our-life`

to work, use this in `.htaccess` or the virtual host of your Apache conf file:

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?article/([a-z\-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /article/index.php?p=$1&i=$2&t=$3 [L]
```